# popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView reduced height of popup menu

Tags: macos, contextmenu

I show a popup menu with popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView at certain screen point. However, if a full heigh of a popup menu with all items is large, this popup menu appears reduced - only several items and arrow icon to scroll down for other items.

I expect to see a popup menu above requested Y coordinate to show a full height of this menu without scrolling, as in other apps (Chrome for example).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Use NSMenu > Size to get a height of a popup menu and calculate optimal screen position of a popup menu.